# How to get message or specific type of Exception working with RestTemplate and exception handlers in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have ***@RestController*** with the method :

```
@PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity doSmth(@RequestBody String json){
            ...
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            String url = "...";
            HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>("body", headers);
            restTemplate.postForLocation(url, requestEntity);
            ....
    }
```

***Application I am calling*** is working in the following way:
1. It returns ***responseEntity***.
2. If something went wrong, It ***throws an exception***.

When It throws an exception, thanks to ***exception handler*** It gives json as an answer with information about the problem.

For example, an exception handler for ***SomeException***:

```
@RestController
@ControllerAdvice
public class SomeExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(SomeException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDetails> handleUserNotFoundException(SomeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        final HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        ErrorDetails errorDetails = new ErrorDetails(new Date(), status.value(), status.getReasonPhrase(), ex.getMessage(),
                request.getDescription(false));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDetails, status);
```

***ErrorDetails*** - just POJO. It's needed to provide clients with information about an exception.

When application i am calling with restTemplate throws an exception,
I recieves ***HttpServerError error***.

```
System.out.println(error); //org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 null
```

***THE PROBLEM***:
I need to know which exception was thrown on another server or which message with, but It gives such answer for any exception with any messages.

***UPDATE:***
*Postman to server:*
1. `@PostMapping` method returns `ResponseEntity` with empty body and `location` header (create operation) so client recieves 201 status code `CREATED` and location.
2. If something went wrong client recieves `json` which is represented by `ErrorDetails`.
*Server to server:*
1. `ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.postForObject(url,requestEntity, ResponseEntity.class);` It works, but even when I try to use `responseEntity.getHeaders()` - it doesn't contain `localtion`.
2. When server throw `SomeException extends RuntimeException` with its handler - depends on status code I have some exception (`HttpServerError for 5xx`).

When I am using `postForUrl` i recieve `location`, but with an exception the situtaion is the same.

Comment: I don't understand the problem

Comment: When something went wrong i need to know what exactly. On another server it could be different exceptions with different messages, on main server an answer is always HttpServerError. I need to distinguish various type of exceptions after restTemplate response